# Video flakes out upon login

Tags: video

Installed 20.04 on a Dell PowerEdge server, and while the OS is running fine and usable via command line, as soon as anyone logs in via the GUI console, sync is lost on the video, I get a horizontal lined mess, and the console is essentially unusable.

With much trial and error and split second timing I was able to hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> at the right time and get the grub menu to come up so I could boot into recovery mode. Doing this and then telling it to continue booting gives me a 1024x768 resolution that works.

Is there some way I can set up the video options via config files so I can boot a bunch of times with different options and figure out one that works?  If so, can I do it universally for every user?

Comment: You haven't said what Ubuntu 20.04 LTS you installed, a desktop release, or server release?  As it's a server, the server system makes more sense, on which did you then install a desktop? if so which desktop?  Does your hardware meet the minimum requirements for Ubuntu Desktop (or whichever desktop you installed?  GNOME has minimum requirements many servers do not need as they usually have server OSes installed, or use a *light* desktop).  Please clarify

Comment: Someone else actually prepared the install image, so I'm not sure.  What's the easiest way to check?

Comment: `sudo cat /var/log/installer/media-info` should display install media info

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS "Focal Fossa" - Release amd64 (20200731)

Comment: Since it has a graphical interface at all, I assume we ended up with the desktop version.  But the graphics chip in the server can handle quite a range of resolutions, so it should be up to snuff.  Would still be good to know how to shut it off or change modes universally upon boot, if it's possible to do so.

Comment: Server graphics card problems can be because they don't meet minimum of "3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB " (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) meaning problems. Yes they can run lighter desktops fine, but GNOME is heavier than most. I'm not convinced you've just got expected problems due to hardware not meeting desktop minimums...

Comment: The card in the server is a Matrox G200eR2 graphics card with 16 MB capacity.  So, definitely less than 256MB.  It wasn't clear from your last sentence, though, whether you think this is definitely the issue.

Comment: Not meeting the minimum video requirements means video issues with Ubuntu Desktop would be expected (esp. on releases past 16.04, with your ram even 16.04). Ubuntu Server will be fine though on it, and if you need a desktop (non-server role) a lighter desktop might still work (sorry for poor wording)